# Missing Maximize, Minimize and Close buttons in Chrome - Ubuntu 18.04.03

Tags: 18.04, gnome, google-chrome

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and am using Google Chrome 86.0.4240.75.
When I maximize the screen the 3 usual buttons disappear. If I take the browser out of maximize status I can see the buttons again. I checked my settings in Ubuntu and don't notice anything that mentions zoom etc. This does not happen to any other programs like phpstorm etc... just Chrome. I also checked the chrome settings and the chrome zoom is at 90%. I also tried to reset the theme to default...no dice. I reset to GTK and no dice. So why are my Min,Max and X buttons gone when I put chrome in full screen mode?

[image: Missing Butons]

Comment: This issue is still present on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version. It usually happens when I click on a link in terminal or VS Code and it opens up using the default browser i.e. Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

This morning I sudo apt-get upgraded my machine and with that chrome was upgraded to the latest version (subversion .111 over .75) and now my buttons have returned. Guess it was just a chrome bug. Hope this helps another ubuntu user.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened with me and I tried closing the chrome and reopening it, but that didn't work. But after some time I reopened the chrome, the buttons reappeared. I think it was just a bug and nothing else.